# How do I construct an order_by for a specific record in a ManyToOne field?

Tags: django, one-to-one, many-to-one

I'm trying to sort (order) by statistical data stored in a ManyToOne relationship. Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    info        = ...
    data        = models.IntegerField(default=0.0)

class Customer(models.Model):
    info        = ...
    purchases   = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='customers', blank=True)

class ProductStats(models.Model):
    ALL         = 0
    YOUNG       = 1
    OLD         = 2
    TYPE = ((ALL, 'All'), (YOUNG, 'Young'), (OLD, 'Old'),)

    stats_type  = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE)
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='stats', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data        = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Then I would like to sort the products by their stats for the ALL demographic (assume every product has a stats connected to it for ALL). This might look something like the following:

```
products = Product.objects.all().order_by('stats__data for stats__stats_type=0')
```

Currently the only solution I can think of is either to create a new stats class just for all and use a OneToOneField for Product. Or, add a OneToOneField for Product pointing to the ALL stats in ProductStats.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about like this using multiple fields in [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
 Product.objects.all().order_by('stats__data', 'stats__stats_type')
 # it will order products from stats 0, then 1 then 2
```

Or if you want to get data for only `stats_type` **0**:

```
 Product.objects.filter(stats__stats_type=0).order_by('stats__data')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the value of the relevant demographic and order by that:

```
from django.db.models import F
Product.objects.all().filter(stats__stats_type=0).annotate(data_for_all=F('stats__data').order_by('data_for_all')
```